# vba code for putting described sign automatically to all columns of a clicked row

Tags: excel, vba

if i double click in column g of any row that is defined i need the symbol to be shown in each column such as h,i,j,k,l,m of the row double clicked in column g
my vba code is

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("h3:m20")) Is Nothing Then

If Target.Value = "Ð" Then
Target.Value = "Ï"
Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "x" Then Target.Value = "Ð"
If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Target.Value = "x"
If Target.Value = Empty Then Target.Value = "Ð"
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G20")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Value = "Ð" Then
Range("G" & Target.Row & "M" & Target.Row).Value = "Ï"
Exit Sub
End If
If Target.Value = "x" Then Range("G" & Target.Row & "M" & Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Range("G" & Target.Row & "M" & Target.Row).Value = "x"
If Target.Value = Empty Then Range("G" & Target.Row & "M" & Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
End If
End Sub
```

this is not working...please help....thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `Range` references are missing a colon. You also mentioned in your explaination:

> *"if i double click in column g of any row that is defined i need the symbol to be shown in each column"*

Right now you checking against an `Intersect` with the wrong `Range`. So try the below instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

'Only activate when its a cell in range `G3:G20`
If Intersect(Target, Range("G3:G20")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Do something here with your values and IF statements
Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Value = "TEST" 'Purely to test

End Sub
```

Not a finished code, but you'll be able to add the missing pieces to the puzzle at the bottom.